# Order by ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As the result of my query I've received `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation` which I want to order by `company_name`. But to get these company name for one `Process` I have to do something like `result_of_query.first&.value`.

Is it possible to inject this line to the query below that the result would be ordered Process by company name?

```
result_of_query = 
Process.joins(:inquiry_field_responses)
       .joins('INNER JOIN inquiry_fields ON inquiry_fields.id = inquiry_field_responses.inquiry_field_id')
       .where(inquiry_fields: { name: 'company_name' })
```

Comment: Which is the model containing the `company_name ` attribute you wanna used to order?

Comment: it's a label for name from db seeds, under this label data is storage

Comment: I don't get it. By the way, it seems you can do `joins(inquiry_fields: :inquiry_field_responses)` to get rid of the second joins there.

Comment: `joins(inquiry_fields: :inquiry_field_responses) ` is a good syntax?

Comment: Sure, that's to join the receiver with inquiery_fields and inquiry_fields with inquiry_field_responses. It's called "nested joins", take a [look](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins).